# Making my navbar form search field full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [navbar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-navbar-ukuuvi?file=index.html) below and I'd like to make the search field in the form full width, so it expands as much of the navbar as possible without pushing anything else out of the way.

How would I do this?

I've tried a couple of different things like setting the width of different elements but nothing seems to work.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">Web App</a>

    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test" aria-expanded="false">        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="test">
      <ul *ngIf="!loggedIn()" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `display:flex;` and wrapping the relevant elements in `divs`. I set the first and second div to `flex-shrink:1;`, which means they shrink to the content of the div. Then I have added `flex-grow: 1;`to the second div so it fills the remaining space.

I also added `width:100%;` to the input field.

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.flex > div {
  padding:0 5px;
  flex-shrink:1;
}
.flex > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
input {
  width:100%;
}
.collapse {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div>
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">Web App</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test" aria-expanded="false">        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Menu</span>      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="test">
        <ul *ngIf="!loggedIn()" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add with and float on the below element:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

CSS:

```
width: 100px;
float: right;
```

The float you set does not work as the width of the element is 100%. You can also set `text-align: center` but depends how you want your text starts.

To align it properly now, use `margin-right` and `margin-left` to display it right where you want.

**Edit:**
To have full width search bar:

```
form, input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row w-100">
   <a class="col-2 navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']" style="max-width:100px">Web App</a>

   <form class="col form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 w-100" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </form>
      
      <button class="col-1 navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test" aria-expanded="false" style="min-width:50px">        
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>      
      </button>      
      
      <div class="col-1 collapse navbar-collapse" id="test">
         <ul *ngIf="!loggedIn()" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">                
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a>              
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">                
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>              
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: well, I just changed mr-auto to ml-auto and that pushed the links to the right, now I just need to make the form search field full width

Comment: yes, I see, but when you shrink the window to mobile the search field and the collapsable region are on different lines. I want them to be on a single line, just like on full desktop

Comment: maybe I should post another question that's more specific?

Comment: I guess so. The initial question "align the menu to right" is solved here. Now open another question to have full width search bar.

Comment: @user1186050 I just added the fix for your full width search bar. Replace the inline styles. It's responsive.

Comment: Just curious, why did you add all the column classes?